# To split and save text in a file using python

Tags: python

Below is the input file sample_text.txt

```
10001ScottTiher100040
10002ScoteTijer100042
10003ScotrTieer100043
10004ScotfTiler100044
10005ScotyTiper100046
10006ScotlTioer100047
10007ScotiTiwer100049
```

I need to save this in the same file as below, can you please help me on this....

```
10001,Scott,Tiher,100040
10002,Scote,Tijer,100042
10003,Scotr,Tieer,100043
10004,Scotf,Tiler,100044
10005,Scoty,Tiper,100046
10006,Scotl,Tioer,100047
10007,Scoti,Tiwer,100049
```

I have tried the below code, but unable to save the b in new file or same file

```
with open('D:\Programs\python\sql_test.txt','r+') as f:
    for line in f:
            for word in line.split():
                b =  str(word[0:5])+ ',' + str(word[5:10]) + ',' + str(word[10:15])+','+ str(word[15:21])         
                print(b)
```

Comment: Have you looked up how to write to a file? You seem to be able to create the strings you want, so ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open two file with `with` context manager: One for input, The other for output.

```
with open("ifilename", 'r') as ifile, open("ofilename", 'w') as ofile:
    for line in ifile:
        print(','.join([line[0:5], line[5:10], line[10:15], line[15:]]), file=ofile)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach

**Demo:**

```
res = []
with open(filename, "r") as infile:
    for i in infile.readlines():
        val = i.strip()
        res.append([val[:5], val[5:10], val[10:15], val[15:]])

with open(filename, "w") as outfile:
    for i in res:
        outfile.write(", ".join(i) + "\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the `reg` is simple to do this:

```
import re

with open("origin.txt", 'r') as in_fd, open("new.txt", 'w') as out_fd:
    for line in in_fd.readlines():
        match = re.match(r"([0-9]+)([a-z]+)([0-9]+)", line, re.I)
        out_fd.write(','.join(match.groups())+ '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `f.write(b)` to save `b` in your file

Answer (score 0):

Very late answer

Your early solution is better without the second loop.

As you know, you cannot have a file with the read option (`r`) and also the write (`w`) option.

The option `r+`, append the transformed data to the end of the file. For the sake of the exercice, we will not use `r+`

Here, we use f to read the file and f1 to write the results, ending with a formatting with a `\n` to jump lines.

```
In [3]: with open('split.txt','r') as f, open('split2.txt','w') as f1: #one file for read and the other one for saving the result
   ...:     for line in f:
   ...:         output = str(line[0:5])+ ',' + str(line[5:10]) + ',' + str(line[10:15])+','+ str(line[15:21])
   ...:         f1.write("{0}{1}".format(output,"\n")) #outputting with \n to jump to the next line for any new line
```